Ping timed out between 2 router from gateway 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.1
i need help issue with my communication between 2 router gateway ip from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.1. here i provide some router details below.
Router A :
Dlink DVG-F2452 (provided by ISP)
gateway ip 192.168.0.1
subnet 255.255.255.0
dhcp enable - 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.254
rear port WAN port connected
ping 8.8.8.8 - successful
Router B :
Tenda D301 (i bought by myself)
gateway ip 192.168.1.1
subnet 255.255.255.0
dhcp enable - 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254
rear port - from router A lan port 1 to router B lan port 1 using lan cable
ping 8.8.8.8 - successful
connect my laptop to each router only using lan cable cat6
scenario issue :
when my laptop connect using router A gateway (192.168.0.1), i cannot ping and access router B (192.168.1.1). ping result is TIMED OUT.
when my laptop connect using router B gateway (192.168.1.1), i can ping and access router A (192.168.0.1) ping result is UP. and also i can access to router B (192.168.1.1) on the same time.
my target is, i want to make router A and router B can communicate each other. so i can access any ip range with different segment using my 2 router anytime like SSH, Remote, Telnet, FTP, SFTP.
any setting missing? like port forwarding, static route, RIP, DNS or something else? i need your help. much appreciated.

It is a traffic rule issue, bascailly, Routeur A isn't allowed to communicate with routeur B but Routeur B is allowed to communicate with A and A is allow to answer is communication, you must check your rule on both routeur and make sure A is allowed to speak with B

Why do you want two seperate routers running 2 different networks ? Now you have NAT behind NAT which is typically unwanted.

@Silbee i plan want to focus connect 200 unit device into Router B using 192.168.1.1 segment. Router A is just for my personal device like Smartphone and Android TV.
